# Cannot call rails API with Neo4j DB, response code 403 instead 200

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, neo4j, postman

I have configured neo4j DB with existing rails app.Neo4j is running in my http://localhost:7474.In this case how can i get my **username and password** for **postman** **Basic auth**.

And i am trying to hit rails API via postman.In postman **Authorization** **type** is **Basic auth** .

when postman hits rails API, rails throwing some "**UnauthenticatedException**" error.

Error in postman,

```
{
    "statusCode": 403,
    "error": "Invalid Session, please login",
    "requestId": "4cc59e17-07c4-4f16-84e0-30c809ff8d0b"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What kind of request is it POST/GET. For POST request you need to include User_id and access_token in the body of your request.

For a get request you need to include the credentials in params

For example

```
http://localhost:3012/api/v1/controller_name/action_name/?&user[id]=1&device[id]=13&device[access_token]=access_token
```

i am using device gem for authentication so the params are like that for your case they may vary

Comment: it is a GET request.

Comment: For a get request you have to include them in the params of the request i have updated the answer with some example